# SSRS summing values from multiple data sets and sub reports

Tags: sql, reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a two data sets and a sub report in my SSRS master report.

I need to create a third - Grand total table or matrix that returns a field from each of the data sets and sub report.

It would look like this (to start)

[image]

To start I built a table and added a columns to test this with the following values. (This is in the Grand Total Row) each element alone is in the respective row.

```
=ReportItems!tps_actual4.Value + ReportItems!Textbox1230.Value
```

tps_actual4 comes from one dataset. 
Textbox1230 comes from a different dataset.

the first error that comes up reads:

```
"The value for the DataSetName property is missing"
```

if i change my code to something that reads like this

```
=First(ReportItems!tps_actual4.Value, "Master_Data_Set") + First(ReportItems!Textbox1230.Value, "Secondary_Data")
```

I get another error that reads:

```
The value expression for the textrun ''.. uses an aggregate function on a report item. Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.
```

There is no one data set we are referencing here. i'm not sure how to resolve this.

The second question is in the case of `Textbox1230` it is returned 6 times as there are six lines of data. How do i specifiy in my logic a case statement when to add `Textbox1230`

lastly I'm not even sure how to reference the sub report as we need to access two of the fields from the sub report as well.

thank you.

```
Grand Total         column1 column2  
Dataset1 Values        a      x  
Dataset2 Values        b      y       … and so on
Subreport Values       c      x  
Grand Total Sums    a+b+c   x+y+z
```

the above is an excel sampling hopefully it will help with the understanding -- the columns will continue the first row of data comes from one data set. The second from another etc and the Grand total adds the values together for a grand total.

Comment: You have your queries that power the other 2 reports right. Build up the aggregate on sql server side (as new query or proc) but with sums of all. You will have to leverage temp tables or variables to accomplish this. Then use ssrs as rendering tool to just anchor the data. This solution WONT work if your calculating data on each tablix.

Comment: @junketsu I thought about that, but the complexity of which we get to these fields is very time intensive and I don't want to duplicate efforts on a third query that takes the pre-existing 3 queries and re-calculates all the data. (very not efficient with resources and time)

Comment: since you are already going to route of looking at each tablix, textbox. And having such complex metrics. Your better off making a proc and doing the leg work once than having another business user get at your team do give a flavor of same report (but with no accounts with values < 9000 just an example) . I have seen enough of these to suggest sql drive and all you have to then do is tweak metric definition to create a new metric. Store on sql server itself.

Comment: I would love to build it out in SQL, but at least for this project the complexity is so diverse and the code for each tablix is so complex that it is definitely not the the ideal. Although it would possibly be a good idea to possibly create a procedure that calls the others and that returns data and updates local tempt tables (again the running and rerunning of complex scrpts i'm afraid will cause a lot of slowness/hit on to the system).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to catch all the totals from different tablixes and summarize these values in a separate tablix. But you cant fetch values from a subreport, this works just with datasets, which are in the actual report. If you want to sum the subreport values as well I recommend to use @junketsu´s solution.

Lets say you have 2 Datasets in your report, each of them is the source of another tablix. In each tablix you need to add a total now

```
'Tablix 1 total
=Sum(Fields!TestValue.Value, "Dataset1")  'This expression is in Textbox1

'Tablix 2 total
=Sum(Fields!TestValue2.Value, "Dataset2")  'This expression is in Textbox2
```

Now add a third tablix. Write in the first textbox the folloing expression:

```
=ReportItems!Textbox1.Value
```

In the second textbox:

```
=ReportItems!Textbox2.Value
```

And in the third textbox:

```
=ReportItems!Textbox1.Value + ReportItems!Textbox2.Value
```

The result for the thrid tablix will look like this:

```
Dataset1 Total Value     11111
Dataset2 Total Value     22222
Overall Total            33333
```

Comment: I found this workaround, it seems unnecessarily cumbersome. I know that a scope has to exist for each data set. but i can't imagine in the world of building SSRS tables no one has attempted to create a 'grand total' or summary type data set.

Comment: It does not work on a new tablix. This only works for Text field