# SSRS - How to use multiple datasets in a single matrix to sum per group value

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report with 5 datasets all the same format and I would like to add a matrix to sum the totals per dataset per group value.
I found this: [SSRS summing values from multiple data sets and sub reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637815/ssrs-summing-values-from-multiple-data-sets-and-sub-reports)
however it only uses 2 datasets and pulls in a value from the second dataset which is not what I need to do. I have not been able to find any posts that work over more than 2 datasets.

I am not able to use UNION to pull the data into a single dataset as it has to be reported in a suitable format to export directly into a template.

This is my Expression for the first dataset: (some will be counts and some will be sums)

[image: Expression for first row]

and this is the resulting table:

[image: results for dataset1]

I managed to get a row per dataset into the matrix for the 4 other tables however the results for those 4 rows were the same across all the the LEPRegion group values, so the grouping had not worked (which makes sense because that is the grouping for dataset 1 only.

[image: Values not split between group values]

Is there a way to get the matrix to use the Indicator Code from each dataset to produce a single row per dataset and at the same time use the values in the LEPRegion field to produce the column values thereby getting a total per dataset,indicator code, and LEPregion?

Comment: are there any common columns between the data sets?  something that you can use to "join" on ? If so.. have a look at lookup and lookupset functions..

Comment: Thank you @Harry - Yes there is and I haven't used lookup other than to pull a single value in - Will research now.